# What's the best way to install Unity and KDE together?

Tags: unity, 16.04, plasma-5

I'm in the process of installing a 16.04 from scratch. I'd like to have both Unity and KDE on my system. Is it better to install Ubuntu and add Plasma Desktop, or should I go for Kubuntu and add Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way will work fine. KDE is just another skin for Ubuntu, and the same goes for Unity. Both ISOs are the same size, so there's no short-term advantage to downloading one or the other.

I recommend you install the one you like the most. That way, if you decide not to install a second DE, or you prefer having a slightly cleaner install, you don't have to worry about installing one DE and uninstalling the other.